# How to click on Website loaded in Gecko within a Visual Basic application [VS2015]

Tags: xpath, visual-studio-2015, gecko

In an HAM RADIO application written in Visual Basic (VS2015) I use the Gecko web browser in a VB form.

On the web site that I load into the Gecko browser with the VB program (URL = http://websdr.ewi.utwente.nl:8901/) I want to click [by software code] from my VB application on the knob "CW-narrow". This knob narrows the receive filter in this Web Based SDR (Software Defined Radio)

This knob is part of a table on the site. I have seen this with FireBug after a right click with the mouse on the CW-Narrow knob(HTML code below).

The 'CW-Narrow' knob is in a table, I cannot manage to click the knob from my VB application.

Who can help?

NOTE:
Another control I need on the same site, the Mute checkbox, is working by using the following VB-code:

- ***GWB_SDR1_MyCall*** is the Gecko browser on the VB form.

*Dim MuteCheck As Gecko.DOM.GeckoInputElement = DirectCast(GWB_SDR1_MyCall.Document.GetElementById("mutecheckbox"), Gecko.DOM.GeckoInputElement)
MuteCheck.Click()*

Running this code indeed mutes the audio on the SDR.

Hope some-one can help me out with clicking on the CW-Narrow knob residing in a table. (See below the copy-paste from the website)

```
<table>
<tbody>
<tr>
<tr>
<td>
<td>
<input type="button" onclick="setmf('cw',-0.78, -0.72);" value="CW-narrow">
</td>
<td>
<td>
<td>
<td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

Many thanks in advance!

Onno de Meijer

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
GWB_SDR1_MyCall.Document.QuerySelector("div.ctl:nth-child(32) > table:nth-child(6) > tbody:nth-child(1) > tr:nth-child(2) > td:nth-child(2) > input:nth-child(1)").Click()
```

I am not familiar with the Gecko API you are trying to use so it is hard to tell which type you need to declare or cast to. As a shortcut you might want to try to use late binding with e.g.

```
Dim CWN As Object = GWB_SDR1_MyCall.Document.QuerySelector("div.ctl:nth-child(32) > table:nth-child(6) > tbody:nth-child(1) > tr:nth-child(2) > td:nth-child(2) > input:nth-child(1)")

CWN.Click()
```

You might need to compile with `Option Strict Off`.

If you continue to have problems then try to use `Dim CWN = GWB_SDR1_MyCall.Document.QuerySelector("div.ctl:nth-child(32) > table:nth-child(6) > tbody:nth-child(1) > tr:nth-child(2) > td:nth-child(2) > input:nth-child(1)")` and then break with the debugger after that instruction and examine the run-time type.

Comment: Exception thrown: 'System.InvalidCastException' in SDR_Monitor.exe

Comment: Try

            Dim CWN As Gecko.Element
            CWN = W.DocumentElement.QuerySelector("div.ctl:nth-child(32) > table:nth-child(6) > tbody:nth-child(1) > tr:nth-child(2) > td:nth-child(2) > input:nth-child(1)")
            Debug.Print(CWN.ToString)

        Catch ex As Exception
            Debug.Print("Error in CW_Narrow SUB")
        End Try

Comment: @Onno, I have edited the answer with some suggestion that might help.

Comment: Solution: Dim CWN As Gecko.DOM.GeckoInputElement = GeckoWeb.Document.Body.QuerySelector("div.ctl:nth-child(32) > table:nth-child(6) > tbody:nth-child(1) > tr:nth-child(2) > td:nth-child(2) > input:nth-child(1)")
        CWN.Click()  AND IS WORKING NOW!!!

Comment: Martin a question : how did you set up the string for the query selector ?

Comment: @Onno, I used Firefox to visit the web page, used the context menu to right click the element and inspect it, then inside the developer tools I used "copy unique selector".

Comment: OK Let me have a look and see if I see the same as you have put in the Query parameter. Thanks again!

Comment: Yes! Got it, if found out how to do this!